# Number of random bits necessary to approximate an arbitrary distribution

Tags: pr.probability, shannon-entropy, sampling

Given a discrete distribution $X$ and $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, consider the minimal $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbf{SD}(f(U^m),X)\leq\varepsilon$, for some (the best, possibly inefficient) deterministic function $f$.  Here $\mathbf{SD}$ represents the statistical variation distance between two distributions, and $U^m$ denotes a uniform sample from $\{0,1\}^m$.  What is the best upper bound for $m$, in terms of $H(X)$ and $\varepsilon$?

It is not too hard to see that $m\leq \log \left|\text{Supp}(X)\right|+\log(1/\varepsilon)$, however, it seems plausible that a better bound exists, such as $H(X)+\log(1/\varepsilon)$ for the entropy function $H$. Yet, I was only able to show that roughly $H(X)/\varepsilon$ bits are sufficient.

It seems like a fundamental problem so I guess it was studied already, but I didn't find an appropriate match. Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no $H(X)+\log(1/\epsilon)$ bound.  I think your $H(X)/\varepsilon$ bound is tight.

Example 1. Suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\dots,2^n\}$.  Then the optimal encoding has something like $m \approx n$ [1].

Example 2. Suppose now that $X$ takes the value 0 with probability $1-\varepsilon$, and otherwise is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\dots,2^n\}$.  Then the optimal encoding has something like $m \approx n + \lg (1/\varepsilon)$ [2].  Also $H(X) \approx \varepsilon n - \varepsilon \log(\epsilon)$.

We can see that Example 2 violates the hypothetical $H(X)+\log(1/\epsilon)$ bound.

Also, in Example 2, $m \approx H(x)/\varepsilon + \lg(1/\varepsilon)$.  This shows that your upper bound of something like $H(X)/\varepsilon$ is tight (assuming it is a correct upper bound, which I did not attempt to prove or check).

---

Footnote [1]:   Why?  Well, for each $i$, $f(U^m)$ must put non-zero probability on at most $2^m$ values of $i$.  Every other $i$ has probability 0 under $f(U^m)$, incurring error $1/2^n$; if there are too many of such $i$, the total error will be too large.  Therefore, the number of such $i$, namely $2^n-2^m$, must be pretty small, so we must have $m \ge n - \text{a little}$.   A more precise estimate is something like $m \approx n + \lg(1-\varepsilon/2)$, but let's ignore the dependence on $\epsilon$ for simplicity.

Footnote [2]: Why?  Again, if $f(U^m)$ puts probability 0 on too many values $i$, then the total error will be too large.  So it must put probability at least $1/2^m$ on most of $1,2,\dots,2^n$, and we need $1/2^m$ to be close to $\epsilon/2^n$.  I think a more precise estimate is something like $m \approx n + \lg(1-\varepsilon/2) + \lg(1/\varepsilon)$, but I haven't checked that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In Example $2$ you can approximate $X$ within SD $\varepsilon$ by outputting $0$, but we can choose $\varepsilon'=\varepsilon/2$.
So following your example I think you can simply look at $1/2,2^{-(n+1)},\dots,2^{-(n+1)}$, then $H(X)=n/2+1$, and you are allowed to miss at most $\varepsilon\cdot2^{n+1}$ elements, so you need at least $1+2^n\cdot(1-2\varepsilon)$, which may be much larger than $2^H/\varepsilon=2^{n/2+1}/\varepsilon$.

Re upper bound, you can show the $2^{H/\varepsilon}$ most likely elements have pr. at least $1-\varepsilon$, then use the image bound.

Comment: @Nathan, Good point.  A simple revision: let $X$ take value 0 with probability ever so slightly smaller than $1-\varepsilon$, say with probability $1-2\varepsilon$.  Then you can't approximate within SD $\varepsilon$ by outputting 0.  Don't you get a bigger gap by using a large probability close to $1-\varepsilon$ for 0, rather than 1/2?

Comment: True, you get a bigger gap by using a larger probability, which is useful for the tightness of $H/\varepsilon+\log(1/\varepsilon)$.